# Infinitive Verbals versus prepositional phrase

Tags: infinitives

I am working through sentence diagrams and continue to have trouble determining when a construction is an infinitive verbal or if it is simply a prepositional phrase.

Example 1:

"Stephanie likes to fix cars"

As per my book, the answer is that "to fix cars" is an infinitive verbal.

Example 2:

"The stain, the sticky spot, needs to be cleared"

As per my book, the answer is that "to be cleared" is simply a preposition.

Any guidance will be much appreciated!

thank you

Comment: What's the name of the book? Why does it say "to be cleared" is simply a preposition? Please edit your question.

Comment: _To fix cars_ and _to be cleared_ are both _to_-infinitival clauses. The "to" functions as a clause subordinator, not a preposition.